# tableView.reloadData() only called once

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm fairly new to Swift and I'm trying to make a tableView appear in a popup as shown here.
[image: tableView]

I have the datasource and delegate set to self and I call reloadData() after fetching data from Cloud Firestore. The thing is, numberOfRowsInSection might get called once, but can't get called again. CellForRowAt never gets called.

Does this have to do with the fact that I made my tableView programmatically? Something like it doesn't think the frame is set or something, even though it is. The table does work if I just make the table in Xcode manually and link an outlet. The sad thing is I do the same thing in a different view controller, but in that view controller it does work and I can't find any differences in the code.

Here's the function that gets called when you press the button

```
@IBAction func ShowTeams(_ sender: Any) {
    RefreshData()
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: self.btnShowTeams.frame.origin.x + 15, y: self.btnShowTeams.frame.origin.y + 23)
    tblTeams = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 180))
    tblTeams.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellTeams")
    let popover = Popover()
    tblTeams.rowHeight = 35
    tblTeams.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
    tblTeams.separatorColor = UIColor(hexFromString: "13293d")
    popover.show(tblTeams, point: startPoint)
}
```

Here are the functions that set up the tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if tableView == tblTeams{
        print("this shows like once, and yes there's data in dataTeams")
        return dataTeams.count
    }else{
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == tblTeams{
        print("this doesnt show")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTeams", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.textLabel!.text = dataTeams[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellInvites", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's the fetch data function

```
func RefreshData(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    dataTeams = [String]()
    var i = 1
    while i <= 6 {
        db.collection("teams").whereField("uid\(i)", isEqualTo: uid)
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        self.dataTeams.append((document["username"] as? String)!)
                    }
                    print("the code does always make it here, I checked")
                    self.tblTeams.reloadData()
                }
        }
        i = i+1
    }
}
```

And the stuff at the top for good measure. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import GradientLoadingBar
import SCLAlertView
import Popover

class Game: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var btnShowTeams: UIButton!
var dataTeams = [String]()
var tblTeams: UITableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tblTeams.dataSource = self
    tblTeams.delegate = self
    RefreshData()
}
```

Comment: When you are calling `reloadData` again just print `tblTeams.dataSource` and `tblTeams.delegate` and check if you are getting anything.

Comment: in `ShowTeams` assign delegate and datasource `tblTeams.dataSource = self    
    tblTeams.delegate = self`and check

Comment: First if it is a popup, you should use UIPopoverPresentationController and separate that tableview code from there and help you to reduce bugs like this. Also as @Dharmesh said check if dataSource and delegate is set or not.

Comment: When you check that two object references point to the same object you should use `===` not `==` so I think each `if tableView == tblTeams` should use `===` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func ShowTeams(_ sender: Any) {
    RefreshData()
    let startPoint = CGPoint(x: self.btnShowTeams.frame.origin.x + 15, y: self.btnShowTeams.frame.origin.y + 23)
    tblTeams = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 180))
    tblTeams.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellTeams")
    let popover = Popover()
    tblTeams.rowHeight = 35
    tblTeams.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
    tblTeams.separatorColor = UIColor(hexFromString: "13293d")
    popover.show(tblTeams, point: startPoint)
}
```

In the above code you're creating new table view every time you click your button. And the newly created tableview has `nil` data source and delegate (by default). 

**So either set data source or delegate in above method**

```
tblTeams.dataSource = self
tblTeams.delegate = self
```

**or reuse the existing table view by replacing**

```
tblTeams = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 180))
```

with

```
tblTeams.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 180)
```